# Участник был удалён и накрутка голосов

Tags: поддержка

На прошлой неделе мне дали бан на неделю из-за какого-то чела, который, как написано в уведомлении сильно много ставил мне голосов "за". На картинке это нижняя запись где отметка -160 за удалённого участника. Аккаунт восстановился на выходных я зашёл, сделал несколько правок, но мне опять списали эту репу. Снова появилась запись "участник был удалён". Я не понимаю что происходит и что с этим сделать
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пройдя по истории немного дальше нашёл ещё
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это разные участники. Удален и удален, постоянно кого-то удаляют, и репутация откатывается, если удаленный участник голосовал за ваши сообщения.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Да, было массовое голосование на некоторых аккаунтах, на моем в том числе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В курсе, знаем, работаем над этим.

Надпись `Участник был удалён` связана со слиянием аккаунтов-дублей у желающих накрутить себе репутацию нечестным путем. Все голоса, отданные удаляемым или сливаемым аккаунтом, аннулируются.

Надпись `Массовое голосование отменено` связана с автоматической отменой голосования, производимой системой слежения за голосами. Данное событие происходит без участия модераторов.

Другими словами, если за вас голосовал чужой бот, и его голоса были аннулированы, то вашей вины в этом нет. Если за вас голосовал ваш бот - то есть, и за это возможно получить блокировку аккаунта.

Comment: а как сделать так, чтобы меня больше не банили за это?

Comment: @SpaceResearcher бан не может быть выдан только по причине что кто-то за вас голосовал, не важно бот это был или нет. Если был бан, значит были и другие причины. Вы получили сообщение от модератора, в нём можете лично уточнить, что именно произошло. Туда можно написать, модераторы ответят, разъяснят если что-то непонятно.

Comment: @SpaceResearcher обновил ответ, добавил уточнений.

Comment: @aepot "Модераторы ответят"? Это такое тонкое издевательство? Несколько раз "туда" писал, ни разу не удосужились ответить.

Comment: @Эникейщик вижу ваше предупреждение от 18 мая, там ничего от вас не написано, или вы про другое?

Comment: @aepot про другое. Давно было, несколько раз писал, потом перестал, потому что бесполезное занятие. А в таких предупреждении было бы полезно писать, какие именно и где "были обнаружены проявления невежливости".

Comment: @Эникейщик если я буду писать предупреждение, то учту обязательно, спасибо за замечание. А так большинство предупреждений отправляется по общему шаблону. А то что давно было - то было давно. :)

Comment: Кстати, мне на en.SO модераторы почему-то не отвечают, вроде там 4X больше модераторов, чем на ru.SO :)

Comment: @PeterKolosov а юзеров в 50 раз больше :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ ааа, точно... :D

Comment: @SpaceResearcher могу ли я еще чем-то помочь?

Comment: @aepot , спасибо большое,пока у меня вроде нет вопросов:)

Comment: @SpaceResearcher хорошо. Если ответ норма, можете его галочкой пометить, вдруг кому-то пригодится )